# Toshiba lap doesn't recognize confirmed USB for boot, Bios is set to USB first

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, bios

I have a Toshiba laptop that was packaged with Win 10 and a 32gig SSD. I successfully installed Ubuntu 16.4 on it using a USB and used it for a time. Now, for reason that I don't know, Ubuntu no longer works at all. When I turn the computer on I see the Toshiba screen and then I am asked to install boot media.

I have created a new install USB that I have confirmed to be working on another Windows based computer. The locked Toshiba does not see it but instructs me to 'install boot media'. I have tried using different USB ports - the laptop has three - and have created installers using Unetbootin, Rufus, Universal.USB.Installer, and YUMI. None work.

I have set my bios boot order to USB first which doesn't work and have then reset the BIOS to default to see if I can jog something useful but it still doesn't work. Have tried with Secure boot both enabled and disabled.The laptop includes Bios 5.0 in which Boot Mode UEFI cannot be changed.

Any ideas about how to get the BIOS to see a USB installer?

Comment: What choices do you get from the EFI boot menu (some function key at power-up which lets you select a boot device/Os)?

Comment: I can only select from between SSD or USB. I've tried with both settings and tried resetting to default. Neither works. With BIOS 5.0 I am unable to modify the UEFI setting. I've tried making at boot stick with GPT for UEFI on Rufus but I can't - when I ask it to make the stick it defaults back to EFI. I've wondered if I need to find a Windows boot, reinstall, and then see if I can reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a bit old now but some computers require the "bootable" flag to be set on the installation media before it will boot to it. So it might be as simple as using `sudo fdisk /dev/sdX` (where sdX is your usb drive) setting the boot flag with `a` and then writing the table to disk with `w` (you can do the same with `cfdisk` which I find easier to navigate). WARNING - if you choose /dev/sdX wrongly you can WIPE ALL DATA from one of your drives that you didn't want to, take care (`dmesg` will tell you the most recently inserted drive).

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be what you are looking for exactly but have you tried using a DVD to boot from? If the BIOS can't recognize a USB perhaps a DVD with a .iso file might work. (This is assuming that you have a DVD player on your laptop at all.)
Do you have a DVD recovery disc for Windows or a USB that came with the laptop? If so, try that and see if that works.
Also, have you tried using a different USB stick? I know you mentioned trying different ports, but perhaps a different device altogether might work.

Comment: Thanks Bob. When I first installed Ubuntu I tried using a disk but the computer BIOS doesn't seem to recognize it. It only lists SSD and USB and boot options. At that time it booted off a stick which I am guessing is because windows was still installed. I do not have a Win recovery sick or disk.

Comment: Hi that really is strange. Is this your only computer? If not then maybe try using the stick on a different PC. I don't think that not having windows would be a problem for it recognizing the stick, ad that should be a BIOS thing, not a Windows thing. But I could be wrong.

Comment: The stick works on my wife's computer with is Windows based. I have two Toshiba laptops with the same BIOS and neither sees an Ubuntu install. Maybe I'll try a Mint install just to try something different. Confusing to me!

Comment: Perhaps try flashing the BIOS to the latest version if it's not already updated?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install windows then on a another choose in rufus windows normal installation and after this put your usb stick into the toshiba notebook.

-> Go in the bios
-> Change your mode from UEFI to CSM
-> USB needs to be the first one who boot
-> save changes & exit
-> enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Just turn off fast BIOS mode from Advanced tab and you'll be all set

Comment: You could explain a bit more how it would works